# Error When Trying to Save a DateTime Value

Tags: dominotogo

I'm trying to save a DateTime value on the Notes document with DominoToGo. I've tried the following:

```
var testDate = "12/31/2014";
doc.replaceItemValue("DueDate", testDate, "datetime");
doc.save(true);
```

This gives me a message in the console:

[INFO] :   09:06:08: NotesDocument.save: new value in XML: 12/31/2014

[INFO] :   09:06:08: NotesDatabase.uploadChanges: FAIL: no response from server. Looks like there is a problem. Check server and Domino To Go XPages.

Any ideas of what I need to check? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a bug in ynmobile_write.xsp, I fixed it and will send you the updated code via mail!